# imdbpy2sql must supply URI fpr the database connection

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm providing the following command, Please tell me where I'm going wrong.

```
**$ imdbpy2sql.py -d /home/santoshvm/Documents/IMDB DataBase/DataFiles -u URI sqlite:////home/santoshvm/Documents/IMDB DataBase/SQLite Database File/IMDB.sqlite --sqlite-transactions**
2012-11-17 20:11:34,585 WARNING [imdbpy.parser.sql.aux] /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IMDbPY-4.9-py2.7.egg/imdb/parser/sql/__init__.py:125: Unable to import the cutils.ratcliff function.  Searching names and titles using the "sql" data access system will be slower.
2012-11-17 20:11:34,586 WARNING [imdbpy.parser.sql.aux] /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IMDbPY-4.9-py2.7.egg/imdb/parser/sql/__init__.py:332: Unable to import the cutils.soundex function.  Searches of movie titles and person names will be a bit slower.
You must supply the URI for the database connection
imdbpy2sql.py usage:
    /usr/local/bin/imdbpy2sql.py -d /directory/with/PlainTextDataFiles/ -u URI [-c /directory/for/CSV_files] [-o sqlobject,sqlalchemy] [-i table,dbm] [--CSV-OPTIONS] [--COMPATIBILITY-OPTIONS]
```

**What is the right way of giving the URI?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have whitespaces in your path :

```
home/santoshvm/Documents/IMDB DataBase/SQLite Database File/IMDB.sqlite
```

You should either rename your directories or escape the whitespace with a "\" :

```
home/santoshvm/Documents/IMDB\ DataBase/SQLite\ Database\ File/IMDB.sqlite
```

Comment: Should have realized that.Now getting AssertionError: No SQLObject driver exists under the name URI